# Postgres jsonb_set - add array element at index larger than current array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to add elements to a jsonb array in Postgres.

In advance I know for sure what index each element will have, but I *don't* know:

- What order I'll be adding the elements in
- What the total number of elements will be

For example if the eventual array is `[0,1,2,3,4]` (with the value corresponding to the index for simplicity) the elements could be added in the order `0,1,3,2,4` or `4,3,2,1,0` etc - it's random, and I just wait for the elements to come through and add them - I don't know how many there will be in advance.

So what I want to do is add each element at its specific index, however I've run into a problem doing this with `json_set`

To set an element at a particular index I'm using the following:

`SELECT jsonb_set('[0,1,2]', '{0}', '3', true)`

**returns** `[3,1,2]`

So that case is fine - however when I want to set an element at an index which is out of bounds for the current array, instead of creating empty spaces in the array, it just appends the element to the end, in a newly created index.

So this works (adding element @ index 3 to length 3 array)

`SELECT jsonb_set('[0,1,2]', '{3}', '3', true)`

**returns** `[0,1,2,3]`

But this doesn't (adding element @ index 5 to length 3 array)

`SELECT jsonb_set('[0,1,2]', '{5}', '5', true)`

**returns** `[0,1,2,5]`

I'd like it to be `[0,1,2,undefined,undefined,5]`

Is there a way to get this to work? I don't really mind what the empty space value is, could be `undefined`, `null` or some placeholder value. I just want to be able to insert elements at any index and have Postgres create a new bigger array for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is explained in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) (one of the notes at the end of the page):

> [...] If the item is out of the range -array_length .. array_length -1, and create_missing is true, the new value is added at the beginning of the array if the item is negative, and at the end of the array if it is positive.

Create your own function:

```
create or replace function jsonb_set_element(jsonb, int, jsonb)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
begin
    while jsonb_array_length($1) < $2 loop
        $1 := $1 || '[null]'::jsonb;
    end loop;
    return jsonb_set($1, array[$2::text], $3, true);
end $$;
```

The function in action:

```
select 
    jsonb_set_element('[0,1,2]', 0, '9') as test_0,
    jsonb_set_element('[0,1,2]', 3, '3') as test_3,
    jsonb_set_element('[0,1,2]', 5, '5') as test_5

  test_0   |    test_3    |          test_5          
-----------+--------------+--------------------------
 [9, 1, 2] | [0, 1, 2, 3] | [0, 1, 2, null, null, 5]
(1 row)
```